Holoviz-Panel: no interactivity when installing into user environment on jupyterhub
I am a user of jupyter-instance which I do not control. We can install our own packages into the user-environment, we can create custom kernels, but we cannot install packages into the base-install/base=environment of the jupyterhub.
I can install the Holoviz-Panel and Holoviz-pycomms into my local user environment and I can create and display panel widgets in my jupyterlab notebooks.
However, there is no interactivity. When I click on the panel widgets, the value of the widgets do not change.
'''checkbutton_group = pn.widgets.CheckButtonGroup(name='Check Button Group', value=['Apple', 'Pear'], options=['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Strawberry'])
checkbutton_group'''
checkbutton_group.value is now: ['Apple', 'Pear']
when I click on 'Banana' the checkbutton for banana is pressed, but checkbutton_group.value remains ['Apple', 'Pear'].
In short, there is no communication between the front end and the back end.
The only solution which I found here appears to be to install panel and pyvizz in the base environment:
https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/panel-in-jupyterlab-no-interactivity/3191/5
This is not an option in my environment. Is there a way to configure my jupyterlab/jupyterlab spawner, custom kernel, to pick up pyvizz from my local environment?
